# Deleted OS off of macbook. How to reinstall?

Tags: macos, mac

Somehow the OS on a used macbook that I bought has gone missing. When I go to Internet recovery to try to reinstall is says "This item is temporarily unavailable, try again later."

It's been saying this every time I've tried for a month now.

Is there some other way to get an OS back onto the machine?

This is my first time working with a Mac.

More info: Macbook A1342

My best guess is it's this: MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.26 13" (Uni/Late 09)

No, this is my first Mac. I might be able to find a friend who has one that can help me out.

Comment: First of all, do you have any information on the model, year made and/or screen size of your Mac? Second, do you have access to any other Mac computers? I ask this because it is possible to download the current version of OS X 10.11.4 operating system to a different Mac, then transfer to a flash drive to install on your Mac. The download is 6 GB in size just to let you know.

Comment: BTW you can make a Genius appointment at an Apple Store and they will help you install the OS via their WiFi or, failing that, via physical media. At no cost to you